# When ajax loads page, links do not work on first click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating search box drop down menu, every thing works fine, but links are not working on first click, or when links are loaded in div, I should first click some where on body then click links. Why it is doing this?

Code is so simple

This one is django code, stays in ajaxsearch.html

```
{% if qUser %}
  {% for i in qUser %}
    <p class="queryP"><a class="queryA" href="/{{ i.username }}/">{{ i.full_name|truncatechars:30 }}</a></p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

This one is my jQuery code

```
function search(box){

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/search/',
      data: {
        'query': $('input[name=search]').val(),
      },
      success: searchSuccess,
      error: searchError,
      dataType: 'html'
    });
}

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
  if(data){
    $('.complete_list').html(data)
  }
}
```

This is the HTML code

```
<div class="section group">
  <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    <div class="complete" style="position:absolute;">
      <div class="complete_list" style="position:relative;width:70%;background:#fff;margin:auto;text-align:left;text-indent:10px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide example code with error

Comment: Sounds like an event delegation problem, although you've not shown any code, so I'm not sure how you expect anyone to help you.

Comment: Please paste code for a solution

Comment: I just updated codes guys, you are right but codes are so simple

Comment: please put the html output

Answer (score 0):

Okey guys I just find the answer by tracking network, I binded the query to keyup, paste and onchange, so when ever the query is finished then last click is querying as well so that first click is not works on links